# Flot chart issue with Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, charts, flot

I am using **Flot.js** library to draw charts in my web application. I am facing a problem sometimes with Firefox browser only , axis labels/ values are not displayed completely . First I think that it could be issue with latency because I was using ajax response / delay so I tried to plot chart using static data but same problem .

Expected Result Should be :-

[image]

But I am getting result like this :-

[image]

Here is my complete code :-

```
var newX = [];
for(var i = 0 ; i< 10 ; i++)
{
    newX.push([i,i+2]);
}
var plot_data = [newX];
myPlot = $.plot( $( plot_container_name ), plot_data ,'');
```

and chart axis values are displayed/ plotted using canvas to I think it should not be the issue with CSS also .
I also checked the returned reference after plotting , it contains the axis values / ticks .

```
 myPlot.getAxes()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you build a code snippet or [fiddle](http.//jsfiddle.net) which shows the problem?

Comment: @Raidri 
As I checked by creating Jsfiddle   https://jsfiddle.net/u30eh5kk/ but its working fine there . It seems that there are something related to time delay because when I applied sleep() on my Server which is replying for AJAX request , then its working as required . Have you faced any such issue before ?